# Installing Orange into a virtualenv

Tags: orange

Linux Mint 17.1 with native Python 2.7.6.

All pre-reqs listed in the INSTALL.txt: python-numpy libqt4-opengl-dev libqt4-dev cmake qt4-qmake python-sip-dev python-qt4 python-qt4-dev python-qwt5-qt4 python-sip graphviz python-networkx python-imaging python-qt4-gl build-essential python-pip python-scipy python-pyparsing ipython python-matplotlib

Has anyone installed orange into a virtualenv? I am trying to install Orange into a virtualenv using pip as follows:

```
$ cd ~/venv/
$ mkdir orange
$ cd orange
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install --global-option="build_pyqt_ext" orange
```

The install begins well enough:

```
Collecting orange
  Using cached Orange-2.7.8.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from orange)
Collecting numpy (from orange)
  Using cached numpy-1.9.1.tar.gz
    Running from numpy source directory.
Collecting scipy (from orange)
  Using cached scipy-0.15.0.tar.gz
```

At this point there is along pause (compilation) and eventually a long list of errors, which I've posted here: http://pastebin.com/VZWyGjfz and I've included the last few lines below:

```
Complete output from command /home/citmkd/venv/orange/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dLY2eU/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" build_pyqt_ext install --record /tmp/pip-r8dA2D-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/citmkd/venv/orange/venv/include/site/python2.7:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-dLY2eU/scipy/setup.py", line 249, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-dLY2eU/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in setup_package

    from numpy.distutils.core import setup

ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/citmkd/venv/orange/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dLY2eU/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" build_pyqt_ext install --record /tmp/pip-r8dA2D-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/citmkd/venv/orange/venv/include/site/python2.7" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dLY2eU/scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error in pip or scipy's setup script (can you try installing numpy, scipy individually i.e `pip install numpy && pip install scipy`).

Note that in any case you should use the system provided numpy, scipy, ... packages by
using `virtualenv --system-site-packages venv` to create the virtual environment.